# Why can a migrated question be halfway reopened?

Tags: bug, migration, vote-to-reopen

I'm a moderator, and I don't migrate very often; when I do, I try to remember to check on the question later to see how wise my decision was.

~12 hours ago I migrated something, then this morning I look at the migrated Q and notice it's been ignored on the other site.  This make me feel bad, so because the other site is much busier and the question has likely now fallen into obscurity, on an impulse I click "reopen", thinking, "You can't do that, it won't work".

**Low and behold, it seems that it does; the `reopen` link is now `close`, and "[on hold]" has been removed from the title.**  However, the big "migrated to" banner is still there, and you can click through to the migrated question, which is *still open*!

This is bad, because now as a moderator I've effectively cross-posted a question.  Whoops.  So I flag the migrated version to let the mods there know.

To finish up, I write a comment on the original saying "Sorry, I was wrong about you getting better help elsewhere, so I've reopened this here again" (which is not such a big deal, because questions 12 hours old are still on our "new" 1st page).

In the process I notice -- whoops again -- **the "Post an Answer" link is not there**.  In other words, it looks like a duck, talks like a duck but  does not walk like a duck.   So what is it?

I have not closed the question again because I fear the migration banner will then just become "off-topic", and, like duplicate chains, I think they are useful.  Someone from our site can still find the migrated Q and post an answer elsewhere.

What's the purpose of this behaviour?  My only guess is that it is to facilitate the question being automatically re-opened if it is bounced from the other side.  Presuming that's what would happen...I don't know.

---

For the curious or doubtful, here's the duck-not-a-duck question:

[ However, now it's been unlocked -- see accepted answer -- "Post an Answer" is back, "migrated to" is still there. And no, it did not explicitly say "locked" anywhere prior to this. ]

[ And now it's been closed on U&L the migration banner is gone to, so nothing to see. ]

Comment: Have you got links to the questions in question? (Remember to include the "noredirect=1" query parameter so us mere mortals don't get redirected).

Comment: @ChrisF Added above.  But you will need to "open in a new tab" or edit  in the query string yourself ;)

Comment: That's OK. I think I can manage that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the question is still locked. Check the "mod" menu under the question to see if it says "lock" or "unlock".

I'm not sure why reopening the question on your site wouldn't unlock the question, but that's not the usual way things happen so might be a case that's not been coded for.

The usual sequence is migrate -> question closed/deleted on target site which rejects the migration leaving the question "on hold" -> reopen.

It's probably such a rare case that unless the fix is easy I can't see it being fixed soon.

BTW. I'd flag the migrated question so the mods on the target site can remove it.

Comment: Unlocking did it, thanks.  I did flag the other question immediately (that's in the question here...then I pinged them to let them know to ignore the flag because it had not been reopened...guess I will have to do one of those two things again).

Comment: @goldilocks rejecting the migration (closing the question on the target site) should have put everything back to normal. At least, the migration banner has been removed from the original question.